# Force a Subclass to Define Extra Fields in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

My company has a base database model class that is subclassed by particular instances of our product. The class represents primary keys in a database. The base class has a field, which we'll call AlwaysPresent, which is common to all instances of the product and is not used in querying.

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
    private string AlwaysPresent
}
```

But it is a requirement that subclasses add at least one more field, as we will use reflection later to treat those other fields as database column names for a query. If there are no other fields, we can't query.

So, my question: is it possible to use C#'s reflection capabilities to force a non-abstract subclass to define new fields without specifying their names?

I am a Python programmer by trade, and I know exactly how to solve this kind of problem in Python using metaclasses. To my knowledge, C# does not have metaclasses. And I cannot raise an exception in the base class constructor, because (for various reasons) we don't use constructors for these classes (just initializers), and even if we did the base class constructor could be overridden.

Comment: You know you can define abstract properties? Which you can then implement as automatic properties?

Comment: @jdv-JandeVaan not without defining the names of those properties..

Comment: You can check this at runtime using reflection, but there's no way to do it at compile time.

Comment: What do you meant by **base class constructor could be overridden**.? Constructor cannot be overridden

Comment: It could be done with [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx). Not saying that's the right way to do it, but it's one possible solution.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Really? Sorry, I'm very new to C#. I just looked up the behavior... perhaps I can add a parameterless constructor to the base class that does the field check.

Comment: No problem. You know about it now. Constructor and destructor can never be overridden. Doing that will help but will impact in performance since reflection is very slow. you can alternatively add abstract property to base class if that suits your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reflection cannot be used to force something. At least not at compile time. Via reflection you can read how a type is. In your case you can probably check its fields and throw an exception if required at run time.

In any case usually it is much better to use properties instead of fields. Properties are more extensible and better to hide the internal structure of a class.

A common way to enforce a specific design  (properties or methods definition) of a class is to use interfaces.You can have also a class that implement more than one interface.

If properties names or fields are not know when designing the interface you cannot enforce your requirements at compile time but only at run time.

Another common c# technique is to decorate properties or fields with attributes.  Maybe you can create a custom attribute and at run time check for fields with that attribute (always with reflection).

Comment: I'll explain it in terms I understand from the dynamic languages world; perhaps that will make it clearer. In Python, I can add a hook into class creation so that at class definition time, the Python interpreter will use reflection to inspect the fields, and then my hook will raise an exception if those fields are not to my liking.

Comment: @mlefavor I am sorry but C# is not Python and you just don't do things that way. The proper way to enforce these kinds of contracts is to have interfaces that you expect the classes to implement.

Comment: @mlefavor: since C# is not a dynamic language like Python, class creation is managed at compile time, and unlike languages like Lisp, there is no way to hook that part of the process (yet). You can only enforce these constraints at run time and test your code thoroughly to make sure nothing violates them.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Again, I can't use an interface since I can't know the field names in advance. So, if the answer is a flat "no, that's not possible" or "no, that's not possible unless certain conditions are followed," that's about as good of an answer as I can ask for. If you edit your answer to say so I'll accept it.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Check if now is more clear for your case.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with aspects, specifically PostSharp. It allows you to execute custom code during compilation (in fact, it hooks on postcompile action) in the CompileTimeValidate:

http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Architectural-Validation

You can of course replace PostSharp with any custom code triggered on postcompile at build-time.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is not a feature in C#, but you can write it like this to force people to implement it

```cs
abstract class BaseClass
{
    private abstract string GetAlwaysPresent();
}
```